# Many focus keywords in SEO by Yoast

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am using SEO by Yoast on my website...

On the home page in the FOCUS KEYWORD for SEO I put the company name... and it is ok. It works.

I was wondering if I could put more focus keywords in that field?

Maybe separated somehow? Like: COMPANY_NAME; BRANCH_OF_BUSINESS

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible / recommendable and Yoast explains why. The focus keyword is not the same as meta keywords.

https://yoast.com/focus-keyword/

Comment: Ok, thanks. But can I put two words like: business software?

Comment: Yes you can put two words.